# Java- Implementation of Bernoulli Numbers in new method

Tags: java, recursion, biginteger, bigdecimal, bernoulli-numbers

I am having trouble editing an existing implementation of [Bernoulli numbers](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/96optimization/Bernoulli.java.html) in Java which has the [BigRational helper class](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/92symbolic/BigRational.java.html). The original implementation puts the calculation of the Bernoulli numbers inside the Main method. I made a new class to return the calculation for individual Bernoulli numbers. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Bernoulli {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 20;
        System.out.println(bern(N));

    }

    public static BigRational bern(int N) {
        BigInteger[][] binomial = new BigInteger[N+1][N+1];
        for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++) binomial[0][n] = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (int n = 0; n <= N; n++) binomial[n][0] = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++)
            for (int k = 1; k <= N; k++)
                binomial[n][k] = binomial[n-1][k-1].add(binomial[n-1][k]);

        BigRational[] bernoulli = new BigRational[N+1];
        bernoulli[0] = new BigRational(1, 1);
        bernoulli[1] = new BigRational(-1, 2);
        for (int k = 2; k < N; k++) {
            bernoulli[k] = new BigRational(0, 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                BigRational coef = new BigRational(binomial[k + 1][k + 1 - i], 
                        BigInteger.ONE);
                bernoulli[k] = bernoulli[k].minus(coef.times(bernoulli[i]));
            }
            bernoulli[k] = bernoulli[k].divides(new BigRational(k+1, 1));
        }
        return bernoulli[N];
    }
}
```

I am looking to do this in order to calculate the [Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function) for even numbers.

[image]

A Test method that I created calculates the denominator of this equation through BigDecimal. I see an upcoming problem, would I need to convert the Bernoulli BigRational into a BigDecimal? I will likely need to adjust the [BigRational class](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/92symbolic/BigRational.java.html) I found.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt("20");

        // precompute binomial coefficients
        BigInteger[][] binomial = new BigInteger[N+1][N+1];
        for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++) binomial[0][n] = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (int n = 0; n <= N; n++) binomial[n][0] = BigInteger.ONE;

        // bottom-up dynamic programming
        for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++)
            for (int k = 1; k <= N; k++)
                binomial[n][k] = binomial[n-1][k-1].add(binomial[n-1][k]);


        // now compute Bernoulli numbers
        BigRational[] bernoulli = new BigRational[N+1];
        bernoulli[0] = new BigRational(1, 1);
        bernoulli[1] = new BigRational(-1, 2);
        for (int k = 2; k < N; k++) {
            bernoulli[k] = new BigRational(0, 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                BigRational coef = new BigRational(binomial[k + 1][k + 1 - i], 
                        BigInteger.ONE);
                bernoulli[k] = bernoulli[k].minus(coef.times(bernoulli[i]));
            }
            bernoulli[k] = bernoulli[k].divides(new BigRational(k+1, 1));
        }
        BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal(6);
        BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal(2);
        System.out.println(fac(n).multiply(two));
        System.out.println("\u03A0^2");


    }

    public static BigDecimal fac(BigDecimal n) {
        if (n.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)) {
            return BigDecimal.ONE;
        }
        return n.multiply(fac(n.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE)));
    }

}
```

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" is too broad. Refactor your code, divide it into smaller method (rule of thumb: each method should do one thing and one thing only!). Create a unit-test for each method and see that you're getting the expected output. Once you've done that - you'll narrow down this huge code block to a specific part which is not working and it will be easier to debug and fix. Good luck!

Comment: I found an alternate way of solving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Vector;
import org.apache.commons.math3.fraction.BigFraction;

/* Generates the Bernoulli number, B_n, by a double sum.
     * @param n The index of the Bernoulli number.
     * @return The Bernoulli number at n.
     */
    private static BigFraction bernoulli(int n) {
        BigFraction result = BigFraction.ZERO;
        for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            BigFraction jSum = BigFraction.ZERO;
            BigInteger bInt = BigInteger.ONE;
            for (int j = 0; j <= k; j++) {
                BigInteger jPowN = (new BigInteger("" + j))
                        .pow(n);
                if (j % 2 == 0) {
                    jSum = jSum.add(bInt.multiply(jPowN));
                } else {
                    jSum = jSum.subtract(bInt.multiply(jPowN));
                }

                /* update binomial(k,j) recursively
                 */
                bInt = bInt.multiply(new BigInteger("" + (k - j))).
                        divide(new BigInteger("" + (j + 1)));
            }
            result = result.add(jSum.divide(new BigInteger("" + (k + 1)))
            );
        }
        return result;
    }
```